# Bestway base de datos información diaria de usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Necesito un poco de luz sobre de qué forma crear una base de datos, me explico.
En una empresa con flota de vehículos, cada persona tiene sus credenciales de usuario y tiene acceso a una base de datos unicamente con la información de su matricula que el mismo aporta diariamente. Es decir, el usuario cada día escribe información, por ejemplo km realizados, hora etc.
Y el administrador de la flota ve todos los datos por matricula y rango de fecha.

Debería crear una bbdd con 1 tabla de Login y una tabla por cada matrícula de vehículo? y dentro de cada tabla Matrícula escribir la info? es factible con 60 matrículas?

Necesito ayuda porque llevo días dándole vueltas y mi lógica no me da para más.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! NO. crear una tabla por dato esta mal (en este caso cada matricula). Deberias tener una tabla sola con los datos de cada matricula.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo utilizar una tabla para los datos maestros, como las matriculas y los usuarios y otra tabla para las transacciones, donde cargar los datos de cada usuario por matricula y los datos de transacción respectivos. Esto en el caso de que accedan a los datos a través de una aplicación donde puedas filtrar el acceso a los registros por login y matricula.

Comment: la zona de respuestas no debería ser ocupada para responder con recomendaciones sino con respuestas claras y objetivas; de hecho la pregunta esta mal planteada, revisa el comentario que le dejaron, por favor revisa [answer]

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion element. Voy a leer el material del link.